# Is PGSQL not executing my index because of the ORDER BY clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails query that looks like this:

```
Person.limit(10).unclaimed_people({})

def unclaimed_people(opts)
  sub_query = where.not(name_id: nil)
  if opts[:q].present?
    query_with_email_or_name(sub_query, opts)
  else
    sub_query.group([:name_id, :effective_name])
             .reorder('MIN(COALESCE(kudo_position,999999999)), lower(effective_name)')
             .select(:name_id)
  end
end
```

Translating to SQL, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT  "people"."name_id" FROM "people" 
  WHERE ("people"."name_id" IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY "people"."name_id", "people"."effective_name"
  ORDER BY MIN(COALESCE(kudo_position,999999999)), lower(effective_name) LIMIT 10
```

Now when I run an `EXPLAIN` on the SQL query, what's returned shows that I am not running an index scan. Here is the `EXPLAIN`:

```
     QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=728151.18..728151.21 rows=10 width=53) (actual time=6333.027..6333.028 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=728151.18..729171.83 rows=408258 width=53) (actual time=6333.024..6333.024 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (min(COALESCE(kudo_position, 999999999))), (lower(effective_name))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=676646.88..719328.87 rows=408258 width=53) (actual time=4077.902..6169.151 rows=946982 loops=1)
               Group Key: name_id, effective_name
               ->  Sort  (cost=676646.88..686041.57 rows=3757877 width=21) (actual time=4077.846..5106.606 rows=3765261 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: name_id, effective_name
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 107808kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..112125.78 rows=3757877 width=21) (actual time=0.035..939.682 rows=3765261 loops=1)
                           Filter: (name_id IS NOT NULL)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 317644
 Planning time: 0.130 ms
 Execution time: 6346.994 ms
```

Pay attention to the bottom part of the query plan. There is a `Seq Scan on people`. This is not what I was expecting, in my development and production database, I have placed an index on the foreign `name_id` field. Here is the proof from the `people` table.

```
"index_people_name_id" btree (name_id) WHERE name_id IS NOT NULL
```

So my question is why would it not be running the index. Could it perhaps be from the `ORDER BY` clause. I read that it could affect the execution of an index. This is the web page where I read it from. [Why isn't my index being used?](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_my_queries_slow.3F_Why_don.27t_they_use_my_indexes.3F)

In particular here is the quote from the page.

> Indexes are normally not used for ORDER BY or to perform joins. A sequential scan followed by an explicit sort is usually faster than an index scan of a large table. However, LIMIT combined with ORDER BY often will use an index because only a small portion of the table is returned.

As you can see from the query, I am using `ORDER BY` combined with `LIMIT` so I would expect the index to be used. Could this be outdated? Is the `ORDER BY` really affecting the query? What am I missing to get the index to work? I'm not particularly versed with the internals of PGSQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no index on `MIN(COALESCE(kudo_position,999999999)), lower(effective_name)` expression which is used to order rows. Why do you belive that PostgreSQL should use an index on X column to sort rows ordered by Y column ?

Comment: @krokodilko: That's actually *the* answer.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Is there a web page where I can read a little bit more on how these indexes work. I don't really understand exactly what the problem is. If the problem is that there are no indexes in the sorted 'y' column. I had a look and found that there is actually an index on `MIN(COALESCE(kudo_position,999999999))`. Here is the index

`"index_people_on_kudo_position" btree ((COALESCE(kudo_position, 999999999)))`